# Unix shell bash 'one-liner' to isolate all parentheses containing a URL that includes ".mp3"

Tags: shell, text-processing, automator

I'm completely new to this Unix bash stuff — and first question here! Hope you guys can help:)

**Problem:**

I have a mass of messy web source code (wrapping/unformatted) containing multiple occurrences of:

('http://www.example.com/path/audio.mp3')

Could you please help with a one-liner (sed/awk...) that will isolate these occurrences of **parentheses containing a URL that includes ".mp3"**, clean leading/trailing "**()**" and " **'** " characters, and then print as list (one per line) to an active .txt file.

**Note:** The one-liner will be used in Automator on Mac as a service/workflow to action on 'selected text.'

Any help would be greatly appreciated as (despite trawling through all the online tuts) I'm completely lost.

Best Regards,

Dave

Comment: Do you ever have more than one mp3 listed per source line?

Comment: Yeah, in some cases (I think). Although, being that it's all unformatted/wrapping source, I honestly don't know "line is defined...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `egrep` with `-o` (output only the parts that match) should do the trick. Try something like this:

```
egrep -o "http://[^'\"]+.mp3" FILENAME
```

Comment: +1: Concise, and answers the question directly.  Also correctly catches multiple instances in a single line.

Comment: It would be nice if the parentheses and quotes were also matched, but not output…  Is this possible, with egrep?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>`awk '{print $2}' FS="('|')" < filename`</strike>

`cat filename | tr ')' '\n' | awk '{print $2}' FS="('|')" > output.txt`

Just replace `filename` with the name of your file containing these lines..

OR

```
echo "your multiline\
text here" | tr ')' '\n' | awk '{print $2}' FS="('|')"
```

JUST A TRY:

`tr ')' '\n' | awk '{print $2}' FS="('|')"`

Comment: That won't catch multiple occurrences on one line.

Comment: True. Corrected to include that.

Comment: How would I use this without "filename" and "output.txt"? Cheers

Comment: You mean like to send input text as a param, and receive list back on the same console?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. I'm using the one-liner in Automator "/bin/bash" on Mac with "Replaces selected text" checked. So the one-liner shouldn't need any "file name" parameters (like the "filename" and "output.txt" in your script), right?

Comment: Franky, I've never used Automator, just bash from command line, so I can't tell. Now, you could try my third version. If that doesn't work, I'm out of ideas :)

Comment: Couldn't get it go, sorry. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

PERL, which Mac should have.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while(<STDIN>)
{
    $_ =~ /.*(http:\/\/.*\.mp3).*/;
    print $1 . '\n';
}
```

Comment: I ran the script in Automator, but got "http://www.italian-flashcards.com/mp3-words-patrick/2239.mp3\n" ... instead of list of all url links ...

Comment: Hmm. Did you only get one line, or is the issue the newline at the end? how many entries were in your input set?

Comment: Yeah, I only got the one back with "\n" tacked on the end. Should have gotten a list of 40 Urls back...

Answer (score 0):

Try to refine the following:

```
perl -ne $'while(/\(\'(http:\/\/[\w.\/]+?\.mp3)\'\)/g) { print "$1\n"; }' < input_file > output_file
```

It read stdin (here: `input_file`) one line at a time, looks for every occurrence of a "url" in that line and prints it to stdout (here: `output_file`) without `('` and `')`.

Comment: I tried this in Automator using "usr/bin/perl", but excluded the "< input_file > output_file" and couldn't get it to go... any ideas?

Comment: There was an error -  I missed the `/`... Sorry for that. Here's a proof concept: `echo -e "cat\ndog('http://someserver/somefile.mp3')mouse\nbee" | perl -ne $'while(/\(\'(http:\/\/[\w.\/]+?\.mp3)\'\)/g) { print "$1\n"; }'`

Comment: Where in the script does the missed "/" go?

Answer (score 0):

This will match the URLs that appear within parentheses and single quotes:

```
grep -Po "(?<=\(')http.*?mp3(?='\))"
```

The URLs are output, one per line, without the parentheses or single quotes. The `-P` option for Perl-compatible regular expressions is available (at least) in GNU and OS X `grep` versions.

Comment: Thanks, Dennis. The script worked, but only printed out 8 of the 40 urls contained within the web source code. Could it be that your script isn't capturing multiple url instances in a single line?

Comment: @dave: No, when I test it with multple URLs on a line and multiple lines as shown in your question it outputs all of them. Can you show me an example of one that it fails to get?